# VBA Hide all sheets that aren't being used in workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have many sheets in a workbook. I have a main sheet/"form" called "JE" and on that sheet there are buttons and macros that lead to other sheets in the workbook. But, the intention is for other users, not myself, to use the workbook. So, I would only like the sheet that is being used to be visible at any given time. At no time do I want more than 1 sheet to be visible by the user. The user can navigate the workbook mainly thru clicking buttons and certain cells in select sheets that will allow them to navigate throughout the entire workbook. I have tried this by adding code into 'ThisWorkbook' module but it doesn't seem to working as I'd like. When I navigate to one sheet and back to another, some sheets remain visible when I'd like them to be hidden so I'm unsure of what other modifications I can make to code below to get my desired result. If anyone can offer up any modifications or changes I can make to accomplish this, I'd really appreciate it.

**UPDATE**: 
I have added this code to my 'ThisWorkbook' Object:

```
 Option Explicit

    Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
      Dim MySh As Worksheet

      For Each MySh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          If MySh.Name <> Sh.Name Then MySh.Visible = 0 
      Next MySh
    End Sub
```

but, when I go to double-click values that usually populate cells in my main sheet ("JE") I get a run-time 1004 error. The values still populate the main sheet but it no longer navigates back to the main sheet as I'd like.

If anyone knows of a solution or a mod I can make, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: When they open the workbook, what sheet is the visible one that should be the "main sheet" for them to work on and only see?

Comment: @BruceWayne The sheet that will be visible and is the "main" sheet is titled "JE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Workbook_SheetActivate`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
  Dim MySh As Worksheet

  For Each MySh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      If MySh.Name <> Sh.Name Then MySh.Visible = 0 'zero - false, 1 - true, 2 - very hidden
  Next MySh
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That seemed to work the best. I have one minor issue that is occurring and I was wondering if you could help resolve it. In other sheets in my workbook, I have values in the A column of these sheets and I am able to double-click these values and they populate cells back in my main sheet ("JE"). When I try to double-click those values i get a run time error of 1004 and when I click 'debg' it highlights `If MySh.Name <> Sh.Name Then **MySh.Visible = 0** 'zero - false, 1 - true, 2 - very hidden`.

Comment: The value being double-clicked still populates the main sheet, it just doesn't navigate back to the main sheet ("JE") like I would like it to. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The code is nice. Simply put it in the Workbook part of the VBA project:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim MySh As Worksheet

    For Each MySh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If MySh.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then MySh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next MySh

End Sub
```

The ThisWorkbook part is here:
[image]

In general, I use always something similar, when I am starting an Excel application. I define two `Arrays` with `Visible` and `Invisible` Worksheets and I iterate over them, making them either visible or not visible. Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideNeeded()

    Dim varSheet                    As Variant
    Dim arrVisibleSheets            As Variant
    Dim arrHiddenSheets             As Variant

    arrVisibleSheets = Array(Sheet1)
    arrHiddenSheets = Array(Sheet2, Sheet3)

    For Each varSheet In arrVisibleSheets
        varSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next varSheet

    For Each varSheet In arrHiddenSheets
        varSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Next varSheet

End Sub
```

`xlSheetVeryHidden` makes it possible to unhide it only from the VB Editor. Otherwise you need `xlSheetHidden`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HideInactive()

Set theActiveSheet = ActiveSheet

For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sheet.Index <> theActiveSheet.Index Then Sheet.Visible = False
Next

End Sub
```

I 've test the code. Thank you for reading.